# Pull Infopath From Templates from Central Admin (2007)

Tags: infopath, migration

I'm tying to move some Infopath form templates from one farm to another as part of a migration. In some cases, the orginal infopath template can't be found. Is there any way to pull the templates down from central admin?

Dan

Comment: Please supply more information: **1.** _... orignal template can't be found..._ In which case you found the orignal template? **2.** Are any of your templates admin deployed templates?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with administrator approved forms, you can get them through Central Admin. For typical form library forms, the template is published to the /Forms folder of the library by default. However, you can check the Advanced Settings for a form library to see if a different location is specified, or if management of content types is allowed and the form template(s) for a content type(s) are stored somewhere else.